# Can you tell me what is wrong with this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

// Determine if the persons age is >= 13 or they are accompanied

```
var age = prompt("How old are you")
var accompanied = prompt("Are you accompanied by an adult")

if (age >= 13 || accompanied == "Yes"){
    console.log("you may see the movie")
}else{
    console.log ("You can not see the movie")
```

Comment: Closing `}` maybe?

Comment: what does your browsers developer tools console say is wrong with your code?

Comment: There should not be any problem other than the missing `}`.

Comment: Semicolons and `}` are missed.

Comment: `}` and also end your statements with `;`,  some times not necessary in js but it&#39;s good practice.

Comment: Why do you think that there is something wrong with your code? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, but you missed some semicolons `;`, and forgot to close a curly bracket `}` at the very end of your `else` statement.

While semicolons are not required for the code to work, you shouldn't write JavaScript code without using them:

- semicolons are a good practice for "clean" programming
- automatic semicolon injection might not work sometimes, so missing semicolons would cause unexpected behavior

```js
var age = prompt("How old are you");
var accompanied = prompt("Are you accompanied by an adult");

if (age >= 13 || accompanied == "Yes") {
  console.log("you may see the movie");
} else {
  console.log("You can not see the movie");
}
```

Comment: Thank you CodeF0x. The help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check below code snippet,

```js
var age = Number(prompt("How old are you"));
var accompanied = prompt("Are you accompanied by an adult");

if (age >= 13 || accompanied == "Yes"){
    console.log("you may see the movie")
}else{
    console.log ("You can not see the movie")
    }
```